# Draw an archimedean spiral in Python with random x, y coordinates

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I draw an archimedean spiral with Python 3 with random x ,y coordinates?  I have this code here:

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
color("blue")
down()
for i in range(200):
    t = i / 20 * pi
    x = (1 + 5 * t) * cos(t)
    y = (1 + 5 * t) * sin(t)
    goto(x, y)
up()
done()
```

However, this spiral can only be drawn on a fixed coordinate. I want to be able to draw a couple of these in different spots with `randint()` generated x, y coordinates.

I've been playing around with it, but with no luck.  Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The turtle starts out with (x, y) set to (0, 0) which is why the spiral is centered on the screen.  You can pick a random location and in the `goto()` add the x, y of that location to the calculated spiral x, y:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi, sin, cos
from random import randint, random

RADIUS = 180  # roughly the radius of a completed spiral

screen = Screen()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

turtle.up()

for _ in range(3):
    x = randint(RADIUS - WIDTH//2, WIDTH//2 - RADIUS)
    y = randint(RADIUS - HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT//2 - RADIUS)
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
    turtle.down()

    for i in range(200):
        t = i / 20 * pi
        dx = (1 + 5 * t) * cos(t)
        dy = (1 + 5 * t) * sin(t)

        turtle.goto(x + dx, y + dy)

    turtle.up()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Would this still work if i wanted to put these spirals in different squares in a grid ?

Comment: of course it would ! You just need to change the `for _ in range(3):` to an iteration over grid cells, and the lines in the loop defining x and y as random integers would need to be defined by the grid cell in question